# friend Function - can't access private field C++

Tags: c++

I'm just started to learn about friend Function.
I followed one of tutorial, but unable to get the code working.
I got quite a number of error I suppose.

my Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sale
{
friend ostream& operator << (ostream, const Sale&);
int receiptNum;
double salesAmt;
public:
    Sale(int,double);
};

Sale::Sale(int num,double sale)
{
    receiptNum = num;
    salesAmt = sale;
}

ostream operator << (ostream& out,const Sale aSale)
{
    out << "Sale #" << aSale.receiptNum << " for $ " << aSale.salesAmt << endl;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Sale aShirt(1567,39.95);
    cout << aShirt;
    return 0;

}
```

Error

```
error: In function 'std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream&, Sale)'
error: 'int Sale::receiptNum' is private
error: 'double Sale::salesAmt' is private
error: 'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private
error: within this context|
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << aShirt'
```

Thanks

Comment: The signatures don't match: => `friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Sale&);` and => `ostream& operator << (ostream& out,const Sale aSale){`

Comment: They're called data members in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friend function and your implementation are defined with a different signature.  So these are different (overloaded) functions:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream, const Sale&);
...
ostream operator << (ostream& out,const Sale aSale) { ... }
```

You have to align both signatures, to make clear to your compiler that you're speaking of the same function:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Sale&);
...
ostream& operator << (ostream& out,const Sale &aSale) { ... }
```

Here the [online demo](http://ideone.com/kgT7FK) that works as you'd expect.

Comment: @stack I just noticed that yoy had also a reference/value mismatch for the ostream argument and the return type.  I've edited my answer accordingly.